# Setting `font-display: swap` on scss imports

Tags: css, sass

I'm importing Fontawesome in my `scss` file and I do it this way:

```
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands';
```

I need to set those fonts to load with the `swap` method as [Web.dev suggests here](https://web.dev/font-display/?utm_source=lighthouse&utm_medium=unknown#how-to-avoid-showing-invisible-text).

I tried adding the display property after the import with no luck:

```
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands';

@font-face {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    font-display: swap;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There is already a overridable variable in font awesome to change `font-display` property. You've to just declare it before importing font awesome. Like this

```
$fa-font-display: swap;

@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands';
```